# Why is memset() incorrectly initializing int?

Tags: c++, c, memset

Why is the output of the following program `84215045`?

```
int grid[110];
int main()
{
    memset(grid, 5, 100 * sizeof(int));
    printf("%d", grid[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would cause the problem you're seeing, but did you intentionally make grid an array of 110, but then only allocate 100 of them?

Comment: If you print that number as a hexadecimal value you may see the problem.

Comment: @Alex : it won't make change cause i'm printing grid[0]

Comment: Right, it just looked typo and I wanted to make sure you were aware of it

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`memset` sets each **byte** of the destination buffer to the specified value.  On your system, an `int` is four bytes, each of which is 5 after the call to `memset`.  Thus, `grid[0]` has the value `0x05050505` (hexadecimal), which is `84215045` in decimal.

Some platforms provide alternative APIs to `memset` that write wider patterns to the destination buffer; for example, on OS X or iOS, you could use:

```
int pattern = 5;
memset_pattern4(grid, &pattern, sizeof grid);
```

to get the behavior that you seem to expect.  What platform are you targeting?

In C++, you should just use `std::fill_n`:

```
std::fill_n(grid, 100, 5);
```

Comment: Windows 7 32-bit // gnu++ compiler

Comment: @Ahmad: I'm not sure if Windows provides such an API; if it does, I'm sure someone else can point it out.

Comment: @Ahmad: didn't notice that you tagged this C++; just use `std::fill`.

Comment: is it safe to assign pointer via memset? what if int isn't equal to uintptr_t

Comment: @Dmitry: It's not totally clear what you're asking, but the examples here don't assume that `int` and `uintptr_t` are the same (the first assumes that `int` is four bytes, but that's a valid assumption where the `memset_pattern4` API is available).

Answer (score 13):

```
memset(grid, 5, 100 * sizeof(int));
```

You are setting 400 bytes, starting at `(char*)grid` and ending at `(char*)grid + (100 * sizeof(int))`, to the value `5` (the casts are necessary here because `memset` deals in *bytes*, whereas pointer arithmetic deals in `objects`.

`84215045` in hex is `0x05050505`; since `int` (on your platform/compiler/etc.) is represented by four bytes, when you print it, you get "four fives."

Comment: Setting (100 * 4) bytes, starting at `&grid[0]`, surely?

Comment: now i can understand your answer :D , but still is there a solution?!

Answer (score 8):

`memset` is about setting bytes, not values. One of the many ways to set array values in C++ is `std::fill_n`:

```
std::fill_n(grid, 100, 5);
```

Comment: this function is faster than looping for all elements ??

Comment: @Ahmad: That function probably does loop over all elements.

Comment: A good compiler will convert both the for loop and `std::fill_n` into either an optimized code sequence that uses wide aligned stores (probably vectors) or a library call that is known to be fast on the target platform.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't use memset.**

You set each byte `[]` of the memory to the value of 5.  Each int is 4 bytes long `[5][5][5][5]`, which the compiler correctly interprets as 5*256*256*256 + 5*256*256 + 5*256 + 5 = 84215045.  Instead, use a for loop, which also doesn't require sizeof().  In general, sizeof() means you're doing something the hard way.

```
for(int i=0; i<110; ++i)
    grid[i] = 5;
```

Comment: i just thought that memset is faster :D

Comment: The backend of `memset` basically just does this.

Comment: @Ahmad, theoretically it might be slightly faster.  In reality, memset makes your program crash.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: how does memset make your program crash, exactly?

Comment: Another reason is for objects where being set to zero is an invalid mistake.  memset will happily make those objects crash.  A for loop will tell you at compile time.

Comment: memset is also easy to misuse, causing too many/few values to be overwritten, whereas a for loop is less error prone.

Comment: Actually, for the specific case of array initialization, I would argue that `memset` is easier to get right, since you can simply use `sizeof array`.  That way, if you change the size of your array in the future, the initialization is automatically kept in sync.

Comment: @Stephen i think in the Scope of arrays it's fine to use memset you are right about that .. but the idea is that it's easy to bug the code

Comment: @Stephen Realistically I would use a container over a c-array anyway.

Comment: Of course, if you're writing C++, this should be a container and `std::fill`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the `memset` writes bytes, with the selected value. Therefore an int will look something like this:

```
00000101 00000101 00000101 00000101
```

Which is then interpreted as 84215045.

Comment: so ... is there any solution for that?! :D

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually said what you want your program to do.

Assuming that you want to set each of the first 100 elements of `grid` to 5 (and ignoring the `100` vs. `110` discrepancy), just do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
    grid[i] = 5;
}
```

I understand that you're concerned about speed, but your concern is probably misplaced.  On the one hand, `memset()` is likely to be optimized and therefore faster than a simple loop.  On the other hand, the optimization is likely to consist of writing more than one byte at a time, which is what this loop does.  On the other other hand, `memset()` is a loop anyway; writing the loop explicitly rather than burying it in a function call doesn't change that.  On the other other other hand, even if the loop is slow, it's not likely to matter; concentrate on writing clear code, and think about optimizing it *if* actual measurements indicate that there's a significant performance issue.

You've spent many orders of magnitude more time writing the question than your computer will spend setting `grid`.

Finally, before I run out of hands (too late!), it doesn't matter how fast `memset()` is if it doesn't do what you want.  (Not setting `grid` at all is even faster!)

Answer (score 1):

If you type `man memset` on your shell, it tells you that

> `void * memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)`

A plain English explanation of this would be, it fills a byte string `b` of length `len` with each byte a value `c`.

For your case,

```
memset(grid, 5, 100 * sizeof(int));
```

Since `sizeof(int)==4`, thus the above code pieces looked like:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    grid[i]=0x05050505;
```

OR

```
char *grid2 = (char*)grid;
for (int i=0; i<100*sizeof(int); i++)
    grid2[i]=0x05;
```

It would print out **84215045**

But in most C code, we want to initialize a piece of memory block to value zero.

- `char` type --> `\0` or `NUL`
- `int` type --> `0`
- `float` type --> `0.0f`
- `double` type --> `0.0`
- pointer type --> `nullptr`

And either **gcc** or **clang** etc. modern compilers can take well care of this for you automatically.

```
// variadic length array (VLA) introduced in C99
int len = 20;
char carr[len];
int iarr[len];
float farr[len];
double darr[len];
memset(carr, 0, sizeof(char)*len);
memset(iarr, 0, sizeof(int)*len);
memset(farr, 0, sizeof(float)*len);
memset(darr, 0, sizeof(double)*len);
for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    printf("%2d: %c\n", i, carr[i]);
    printf("%2d: %i\n", i, iarr[i]);
    printf("%2d: %f\n", i, farr[i]);
    printf("%2d: %lf\n", i, darr[i]);
}
```

But be aware, C ISO Committee does not imposed such definitions, it is compiler-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Since the memset writes bytes,I usually use it to set an int array to zero like:

```
int a[100];
memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
```

or you can use it to set a char array,since a char is exactly a byte:

```
char a[100];
memset(a,'*',sizeof(a));
```

what's more,an int array can also be set to -1 by memset:

```
memset(a,-1,sizeof(a));
```

This is because -1 is 0xffffffff in int,and is 0xff in char(a byte).

Answer (score 0):

This code has been tested. Here is a way to memset an "Integer" array to a value between 0 to 255.

```
MinColCost=new unsigned char[(Len+1) * sizeof(int)];

memset(MinColCost,0x5,(Len+1)*sizeof(int));

memset(MinColCost,0xff,(Len+1)*sizeof(int));
```