# Initialize a two-dimensional std::array of type enum class (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, stdarray, enum-class

I have the following class in C++11:

```
class MyTable
{
    public:
    enum class EntryType
    {
        USED, FREE
    };

    MyTable(EntryType value)
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            memset(_table[i].data(), (int)value, sizeof(_table[0][0]) * 50);
        }
    }
    array<array<EntryType, 50>, 10> _table;
}
```

Trying to construct an object of MyTable with value of EntryType::FREE, every item in the 2-dimensional array has the value of 0x01010101 (1b every 8 bits), instead of the expected value of just 0x1

I'm guessing it has something to do with my `value` being casted to `int`, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do in order to fix it.

Comment: Why do you use memset to initialize the values at all, instead of directly assigning them?

Comment: That's how `memset` is supposed to work, it initializes byte-wise.

Comment: Just use manual initialization. If you will try to set `1` to `int` type via `memset()` is will be `0x01010101` and it's defined behaviour

Comment: Your implementation is not very memory efficient, if you do not need 32bit enum you can use an array of uint8_t, and then your memset() call will succeeed.

Comment: @gabry you are right, but memory is not an issue for my current task.

Comment: @renzo Implementation-defined behaviour, you mean? The `sizeof(int)` is not necessarily 16 bits as that hex pattern implies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`memset()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) is expected to work that way, since it's

> sets each byte of the destination buffer to the specified value.

Read more in [Why is memset() incorrectly initializing int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100529/why-is-memset-incorrectly-initializing-int)

However, be careful, since as juanchopanza said, [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/) may have padding at the end (read more in [std::array alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262963/stdarray-alignment)
), which means that this approach might fail.

---

Since it's a 2D array, you could use a range-based-for loop and [`std::array::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/fill/), like this:

```
for(auto& row : _table)
    row.fill(value);
```

as renzo stated.

In case you do not want to set every row at the same value, you could do it like this of course:

```
for(auto &row : array)
    for(auto &col : row)
         col = value;
```

Read more in [range-based for on multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317220/range-based-for-on-multi-dimensional-array).

Comment: range-based-for could also be used.

Comment: Or another variant:

    `for(auto& array : _table)  array.fill(value);`

Comment: `std::array` can have padding at the end, so `memset` isn't guaranteed to work when used as in OP's code.

Comment: @juanchopanza ah thank you, didn't know that! Thank you The Techel and renzo for the suggestions, they really improved the answer! =)

Comment: That solved my problem, thank you for the detailed reply. The `int` in `memset` threw me off, as I was not aware it is casted to `unsigned char`

Comment: @juanchopanza (notwithstanding how the implementation putting padding there seems stupid to me) Why would padding at the end make any difference to this? The `memset` would be performed from the beginning until the last element, inclusive. The padding at the end, after the last element, should not be touched nor read, so it shouldn't be relevant at all.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a ranged-based for loop and the [`std::array::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) member function.

```
MyTable(EntryType value)
{
    for (auto& row : _table) {
        row.fill(value);
    }
}
```

This will continue to work even if you change the array dimensions.